# C++ Boost::filesystem::path with unicode characters

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I am new to C++, need a little help here. I have three folders - one in English, one in Japanese and one in Russian for test purposes. When I run this little program

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

void iterateDirs(const path &dir_path, vector<path> &dir)
{
    if ( exists( dir_path ) )
    {
        directory_iterator end_itr;
        for ( directory_iterator itr(dir_path); itr != end_itr; ++itr ) {
            if ( is_directory(itr->status()) ) {
                cout << *itr << endl;
                dir.push_back(itr->path());
                cout << dir.size() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<path> dirs;

    iterateDirs("D:/Test", dirs);
    for (path p : dirs) {
        cout << p << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

only english letters are recognized.
This is how the output looks

```
D:/Test\lol"
1
"D:/Test\С‹СЋС‹"
2
"D:/Test\???"
3
"D:/Test\lol"
"D:/Test\С‹СЋС‹"
"D:/Test\???"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It doesnt seem like only cout problem, because when I am trying to do anything (like open these folders in explorer using winapi) with vector items, only english-named folder is recognized by the program code.

I have searched this site and google for solutions and neither of them worked. Tried using wcout wstring wchar_t etc nothing works.

Using mingw w64 4.0 with gcc and clion/cmake on windows 8.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately unicode output to windows console is not easy task. Most reliable way to do it - is to use _cputws or WriteConsoleW - but these functions write directly to console and streams redirections don't work with them. This program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
using namespace std;

void iterateDirs(const path &dir_path, vector<path> &dir)
{
    if ( exists( dir_path ) )
    {
        directory_iterator end_itr;
        for ( directory_iterator itr(dir_path); itr != end_itr; ++itr ) {
            if ( is_directory(itr->status()) ) {
                _cputws(itr->path().wstring().c_str());
                _cputws(L"\n");
                dir.push_back(itr->path());
                cout << dir.size() << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<path> dirs;

    iterateDirs(".", dirs);
    for (path p : dirs) {
        _cputws(p.wstring().c_str());
        _cputws(L"\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

produces next output in cmd with raster fonts:

```
C:\w\1>test
.\CMakeFiles
1
.\??????????????
2
.\CMakeFiles
.\??????????????
```

and next output in cmd in [conemu](http://conemu.github.io/)

```
C:\w\1>test
.\CMakeFiles
1
.\اختبارテスト試験Про
2
.\CMakeFiles
.\اختبارテスト試験Про
```

So before running your app, you need to make sure that you could see directory names with `dir` for example.